# phpmyadmin login not working no matter how much I've changed files

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mamp

I am trying to access phpmyadmin with username 'root' and password '' (blank), but it returns [image: Access Denied]

I've checked the password settings in the files of the phpmyadmin folder that is in my project folder. They are:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

from config.default.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

this one is the same line, but from config.sample.inc.php

I've searched this up many times, but none of the solutions seem to work. It has never worked before, I'm doing this for the first time. Could someone give help?
Also, I have MAMP installed to run php files, but I'm not trying to use the phpmyadmin that comes with MAMP - I instead am trying to use a phpmyadmin (which I downloaded from phpmyadmin.net) that is in my project folder. Is it recommended that I use MAMP phpmyadmin instead? If I publish my website, how will my files be able to keep in touch with MAMP phpmyadmin?
(I am on Windows, if this is necessary)

Answer (score 0):

You Can just put the user name and a blink password i found this

Go to My Computer > C Drive > (Your Local Server Folder, WAMP/MAMP/XAMPP) > APPS > PHPMYADMIN > config.inc.php.
Find the following line of code: $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; // MySQL password.
Change the 'password' to the newly chosen password you created in Step #2.
Click Save.